# Dev extreme Left panel filter headers not coming in export

Tags: model-view-controller, pivot, pivot-table, devexpress, devextreme

I am using Dev extreme pivot grid control.
When I am exporting the data left panel filters not showing in excel. Please refer to my screen cuts.

[image]

[image]

My code is

function onExporting(e) {

```
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Data');
var grid = e.component;
DevExpress.excelExporter.exportPivotGrid({
    component: grid,
    worksheet: worksheet,
    topLeftCell: { row: 4, column: 1 },
    keepColumnWidths: false
}).then(function (cellRange) {
    
}).then(function () {
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
        saveAs(new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'Datas.xlsx');
    });
});
e.cancel = true;
```

}